# How do I Hangup/end Twilio call in Python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, twilio

Am creating a calling app with python 3 and kivy. I can successfully make a call but i cant end it.
I want to create a function when it's called it will end the call.

i have tried code below but failed.
status='completed' still din't work for me

```
def end_call(self):
    end = self.start_call() #phone call initiating function
    end.update(status='completed')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone encounters this issue, this is how I solved it.

```
def end_call():
    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
    call = client.calls.list()
    end_call = call[0].update(status="completed") #get the last call
    return end_call
```

I hope it will help someone.